# Minstrel Stat & Skill Build

Tags: ragnarok-online

I stopped playing Ragnarok Online about two years ago, and I was surprised to find that my Bard is still there when I tried to log in this morning. However, while exploring online about what's new, I found out that the the 3rd Jobs were already implemented!

So, my question: Can anyone here suggest a stat & skill build for the [minstrel](http://ro.doddlercon.com/wiki/index.php?title=Minstrel), the Bard's 3rd Job? I'm not sure whether to go Damage-dealer or Full-support, and I'd like some input there too~

Answer (score 1):

Full Support minstrel and wanderer are build more support there sever rainstorm skill is just for leveling solo but all of there skill are for support like gloomy it helps a lot to a swordsman type and many much more try to build your stat with dex int and vit